# Can't run `apt --fix-broken install` as normal user

Tags: linux, apt, sudo

```
`apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?`
```

How can I get permission?

Before, I typed:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

The result was:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs : Depends: emacs-gtk (>= 1:26.1) but it is not installed or
                  emacs-lucid (>= 1:26.1) but it is not installed or
                  emacs-nox (>= 1:26.1) but it is not installed
 emacs-bin-common : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2+deb10u2) but it is not installed
 emacs-el : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2+deb10u2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: did you actually run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` - the error even asks "are you root?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Answer:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Reason:
The error is probably related to the user permissions.

`sudo` command is used to elevate the user permission. That is why the first command:
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not fail with permission denied.

You can either try to elevate the user permission with sudo, before running fix-broken install. Or you can try to manually install missing dependencies:
`sudo apt-get install emacs-common`

Comment: Oh, I just had to become root with `su`.